# What's the vulnerability in my contract?

Tags: solidity, gas, security, gas-price, vulnerability

I've got a contract deployed at `0xe559835D7979dAe994331DEfaEc2FBA057E56C27`
on the mainnet.

Every time I go to call the `payable` function, which is `solve`, a bot beats me to it.  My transaction gets rejected and theirs goes through.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

// deployed at 
// 0xe559835d7979dae994331defaec2fba057e56c27

contract EqHunt {

  struct Equation {
    string repr;
    int answer;
    bool exists;
  }

  mapping(string => Equation) equations;
  mapping(string => address[]) public solvers;
  address payable private owner;

  uint256 public lastSolveTime;

  uint256 private delay;

  constructor() public payable {
    owner = msg.sender;
    lastSolveTime = now;
    delay = 10 minutes;
  }

  function locked() public view returns(bool) {
    if(now - lastSolveTime <= delay) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function create(string memory _id, string memory _repr, int _answer) public {

    require(msg.sender == owner);

    require(!equations[_id].exists);

    Equation memory e = Equation(_repr, _answer, true);

    equations[_id] = e;

  }

  function getEquation(string memory _id) public view returns(string memory) {
    return equations[_id].repr;
  }

  function check(string memory _id, int _answer) internal view returns(bool) {

    require(equations[_id].exists);

    if(equations[_id].answer == _answer) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  function rand() internal view returns(uint256) {
    return uint256(uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(block.timestamp)))%10) + 1;
  }

  function payout() internal view returns(uint256) {
    return 40000000000000000/rand();
  }

  function reward(address payable _payee) internal {

    uint256 r = payout();

    require(address(this).balance>=r);

    require(now - lastSolveTime > delay);

    _payee.transfer(r);

    lastSolveTime = now;

  }

  function solve(string memory _id, int256 _answer) public payable {
    require(!hasSolved(_id));
    bool correct = check(_id, _answer);
    require(correct);
    if(correct) {
      addSolver(_id);
      reward(msg.sender);
    }
  }

  function addSolver(string memory _id) internal {
    solvers[_id].push(msg.sender);
  }

  function hasSolved(string memory _id) internal view returns(bool) {
    address[] memory _solvers = solvers[_id];
    for(uint256 i=0; i<_solvers.length; i++) {
      if(_solvers[i] == msg.sender) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  function getNumSolvers(string memory _id) public view returns(uint256) {
    address[] memory _solvers = solvers[_id];
    return _solvers.length;
  }

  function getSolvers(string memory _id) public view returns(address[] memory) {
    return solvers[_id];
  }

  function withdraw() public payable {
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    owner.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

  function() payable external {}

  // // TEST CODE
  //
  // function testRand() public view returns(uint256) {
  //   return rand();
  // }
  //
  // function testPayout() public view returns(uint256) {
  //   return payout();
  // }
  //
  // function testReward(address payable _payee) public {
  //   lastSolveTime -= 10 minutes;
  //   reward(_payee);
  // }
  //
  // function getBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
  //   return address(this).balance;
  // }
  //
  // function testHasSolved(string memory _id) public view returns(bool) {
  //   return hasSolved(_id);
  // }
  //
  // function testCheck(string memory _id, int _answer) public view returns(bool) {
  //   return check(_id, _answer);
  // }

}
```

I want real people interacting with the contract, not bots - I thought using a 4 character ID would prevent that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you are being [front run](https://consensys.github.io/smart-contract-best-practices/known_attacks/#front-running-aka-transaction-ordering-dependence). This means that a bot is watching you send a transaction, reading the input (specifically, `_answer`), and submitting a transaction with the correct answer but a higher `gasPrice`. A miner will accept their transaction before yours, causing theirs to succeed and yours to fail.

You can see that this is, in fact, what is happening by observing [your transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd340ccf808f45105d2b1d42882c975395a167cb029516e93d11d428034e28a23) and the [attacker's transaction](https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa8e0c323c9b421da6714c334b8600593e53dba619be04c134da9205fa86d9f43). You will see that the attacker used 5 Gwei as a `gasPrice` while you used only 3. A miner will accept their transaction first because the miner will be rewarded with a higher tx fee.

In order to avoid this, you will have to rearchitect your contract. You can use a [commit-reveal](https://hackernoon.com/libsubmarine-temporarily-hide-transactions-on-ethereum-cheaply-6910191f46f2) scheme, or something similar to fix this.